# Evaluate: $\sum _{k=2}^{n}\frac{n!}{(n-k)!(k-2)!}$.

Tags: summation

Let $n ≥ 2$. Evaluate:

$$\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{n!}{(n-k)!(k-2)!}$$

---

unable to solve this series problem.

Answer (score 6):

Differentiating the both sides of 
$$(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^k$$
will give you
$$n(1+x)^{n-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}kx^{k-1}.$$
Differentiating the both sides of this equation will give you
$$n(n-1)(1+x)^{n-2}=\sum_{k=2}^{n}\binom{n}{k}k(k-1)x^{k-2}.$$

Hence, setting $x=1$ gives you
$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{n!}{(n-k)!(k-2)!}&=\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}\cdot k(k-1)\\&=\sum_{k=2}^{n}\binom{n}{k}k(k-1)\\&=n(n-1)(1+1)^{n-2}\\&=n(n-1)\cdot 2^{n-2}.\end{align}$$

Comment: If you have changed 'differenciating' into 'differentiating' then you will receive another upvote :-).

Comment: oh, my god! thanks!:)

Answer (score 4):

**Hint1**:

$$\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{n!}{\left(n-k\right)!\left(k-2\right)!}=n\left(n-1\right)\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\binom{n-2}{k}$$

**Hint2**:

$$\left(p+q\right)^{m}=\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{m}{k}p^{k}q^{m-k}$$ What
happens if $p=q=1$?